# Avoid ggplot sorting the x-axis while plotting geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data which I want to plot with ggplot:

```
SC_LTSL_BM    16.8275
SC_STSL_BM    17.3914
proB_FrBC_FL   122.1580
preB_FrD_FL    18.5051
B_Fo_Sp    14.4693
B_GC_Sp    15.4986
```

What I want to do is to make a bar plot and maintain the order of the bar,
(i.e. starting with `SC_LTSL_BM ...B_GC_Sp`). But the default behavior of
ggplot geom_bar is to sort them. How can I avoid that?

```
  library(ggplot2)
  dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1469904/plain/")
  pdf("~/Desktop/test.pdf")
  ggplot(dat,aes(x=V1,y=V2))+geom_bar()
  dev.off()
```

The current figure looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to tell ggplot that you've got an ordered factor already, so it doesn't automatically order it for you.

```
dat <- read.table(text=
"SC_LTSL_BM    16.8275
SC_STSL_BM    17.3914
proB_FrBC_FL   122.1580
preB_FrD_FL    18.5051
B_Fo_Sp    14.4693
B_GC_Sp    15.4986", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# make V1 an ordered factor
dat$V1 <- factor(dat$V1, levels = dat$V1)

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x=V1,y=V2))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: And, to be technically nitpicky, it *does* order it for you. The default is alphabetical ordering---it's hardly ever what you want but it's hard to imagine a more sensible default.

Comment: @Gregor I could have not known it was arranged by alphabetical order until you mentioned it. Thanks

Answer (score 53):

Here is an approach that does not modify the original data, but uses `scale_x_discrete`. From `?scale_x_discrete`, "Use limits to adjust the which levels (and in what order) are displayed". For example:

```
dat <- read.table(text=
                "SC_LTSL_BM    16.8275
              SC_STSL_BM    17.3914
              proB_FrBC_FL   122.1580
              preB_FrD_FL    18.5051
              B_Fo_Sp    14.4693
              B_GC_Sp    15.4986", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x=V1,y=V2))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=dat$V1)
```

[image]

Comment: I would argue that this is the superior answer because it is compatible with stacked bar plots, which will have the same ID repeated in a column, and thus will not be compatible with transforming into a sortable factor.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to avoid changing the original data, then you can use `fct_inorder` from `forcats` (part of `tidyverse`) to keep the original order of the data along the x-axis (rather than it being changed to alphabetical).

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = fct_inorder(V1), y = V2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

**Output**

[image]

Another option with `forcats` is to manually specify the order with `fct_relevel`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(
  x = fct_relevel(
    V1,
    "SC_LTSL_BM",
    "SC_STSL_BM",
    "proB_FrBC_FL",
    "preB_FrD_FL",
    "B_Fo_Sp",
    "B_GC_Sp"
  ),
  y = V2
)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("Category")
```

**Data**

```
dat <- structure(list(
  V1 = c(
    "SC_LTSL_BM",
    "SC_STSL_BM",
    "proB_FrBC_FL",
    "preB_FrD_FL",
    "B_Fo_Sp",
    "B_GC_Sp"
  ),
  V2 = c(16.8275, 17.3914,
         122.158, 18.5051, 14.4693, 15.4986)
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 10):

dplyr lets you easily create a `row` column that you can reorder by in ggplot.

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- read.table("...") %>% mutate(row = row_number())
ggplot(df,aes(x=reorder(V1,row),y=V2))+geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also just re-order the corresponding factor as described [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7433_4537ea5073dc4162950abb715f513469.html)

```
x$name <- factor(x$name, levels = x$name[order(x$val)])
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, ggplot wants you to specify a variable as a factor if you don't want it to presume the order to display things in. Using the `readr` library is the easiest way to do this if you're working with data that has already been ordered.

Instead of the `read.table` function, use `read_table` and as part of the `col_types` argument, specify the column with the labels (`V1` in this case) as a factor. For small datasets like this a simple format string is often the easiest way

```
dat <- read_table("http://dpaste.com/1469904/plain/", col_types = "fd")
```

The string `"fd"` tells `read_table` that the first column is a factor and the second column is a double. The help file for the function includes a character mapping for other types of data.