# Wrong X axis order when using geom_bar() with character X object

Tags: r, ggplot2

Considering the bar plot prvided by the following code:

```
y<-rnorm(10)
x<-c('0~0.1','0.1~0.2','0.2~0.3','0.3~0.4','0.4~0.5','0.5~0.6','0.6~0.7','0.7~0.8','0.8~0.9','0.9~1')
data<-data.frame(x,y)
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_bar(stat="identity",fill='light blue')
```

The result is like this:
[image]

It is strange that the `0~0.1` is located at the end of X axis even though the `0~0.1` is at the first row of `data`.

However, when I change the `'0~0.1'` into `'0.0~0.1'`, I got the right plot.

Why this happen? And is there any other way to enforece the order of x axis correspond to the initial data order?

Comment: ggplot is ordering the data in its alphabetic order. You can see this by running `sort(x)` and looking at the output. To set character data to the order you want, convert it to a factor. In this case, before creating the plot do `data$x = factor(data$x, levels=x)`. This works because the vector `x` is already ordered the way you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the order of a discrete x scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create `x` variable as `factor` and make sure the levels are properly ordered in it. In this example, you created a variable `x` which has the levels in proper order. If not, you have to assign a properly ordered vector to `levels` argument in `x <- factor( x, levels = properly_ordered_vector )`.

Also, make sure there is no duplicate values in the properly_ordered_vector, while assigning levels to a factor variable. Once you set it up like this, then ggplot will take care of order of xaxis labels based on the order of levels.

```
set.seed(1L)
y<-rnorm(10)
x<- c('0~0.1','0.1~0.2','0.2~0.3','0.3~0.4','0.4~0.5','0.5~0.6','0.6~0.7','0.7~0.8','0.8~0.9','0.9~1')
x <- factor( x, levels = x )
data<-data.frame(x,y)
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_bar(stat="identity",fill='light blue')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neither worked for me. The best solution for me, analog as described by [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217594/prevent-ggplot2-from-automatically-ordering-x-axis?noredirect=1&lq=1).
The x- variable should be a "**factor**" (whatever that means...) so that is treated discrete and the x-data then as **levels**. Don´t know why to specify twice, but it works. 
For example:

```
mbar <- data.frame(klasse=c("<39", "40-60", "60-80", "80-100", ">100"), len=c(375, 57, 7, 0, 0))
p <- ggplot(data=mbar, aes(x=factor(klasse, levels=klasse), y=len)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p
```